# Searching the Java API?

Tags: java, javadoc

I recently found this which is great as its the API but it doesn't seem to allow me to search

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

I am coming from a .NET background so need to be able to search the API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:[KiwiDoc - A fresh way to browse and search javadoc](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/)

[image]

Auto-completion rocks!

Comment: This one is discontinued.

Comment: This one is no longer offered. What a pity...

Answer (score 4):

For searching in the class/package names and within classes I can highly recommend the [javadoc-search-frame](http://code.google.com/p/javadoc-search-frame/). It's available for Google Chrome as an Extension and for all browsers that can run userscripts.

It provides a pretty useful quick-search functionality.

For a full-text search, I'd use Google as well.

Comment: Simple and quick. This extension adds a small search box to java api docs web site when viewed in google chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Just use google

http://www.google.ee/search?q=RuntimeException+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F6%2Fdocs%2Fapi

Comment: Oracle Docs has a search feature for Java 9 and later. For earlier versions, you can use this (more generic) URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api%20%s as a search engine template in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Use DMelt search

http://jwork.org/dmelt/search/

It searches words in the complete Java JDK 9, plus in 40,000 classes of external community Java packages

Answer (score -1):

Just use CTRL+F in your browser.